Faster glossary generation
I am trying to make a table of contents for my queryset in Django like this:
def get_toc(self):
    toc = {}
    qs = self.get_queryset()
    idx = set()
    for q in qs:
        idx.add(q.title[0])
    idx = list(idx)
    idx.sort()
    for i in idx:
        toc[i] = []
        for q in qs:
            if q.title[0] == i:
                toc[i].append(q)
    return toc

But it has time complexity O(n^2). Is there a better way to do it?
UPDATE
I meant glossary, not table of contents.

If you were to use a cache decorator, it might not matter how inefficient the method was, assuming your ToC was not updated all that often.

So what is title? Is this an table of contents, or a glossary?

@JonSG Using cache decorators for instance methods is a pain, though, as they lead to memory leaks, and it's hard to define a cache key. In this case, for example, self.get_queryset() should be the key but it's not a method argument.

This doesn't look like a table of contents, but a glossary, where you map the first character of a term to a list of terms.
We can work with .groupby(…) [python-doc] here:
from itertools import groupby

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(
        self.get_queryset().order_by('title'), lambda x: x.title[0]
    )
}

Instead of iterating over all queries for every item in idx, iterate through qs as the outermost and only for loop, adding each query to the appropriate bucket. Something like this:
def get_toc(self):
    toc = {}
    qs = self.get_queryset()

    for q in qs:
        t = q.title[0]
        toc[t].setdefault(t, []).append(value)

    return toc



I believe this is equivalent to the above but should be much faster as it uses the database engine to do the sorting and de-duplication:
def get_toc(self):
    return {
        q.title[0]: q
        for q in self.get_queryset().distinct("title").order_by('title')
    }

